# Mongoose 3 to 6 and modelSchemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm working on migrating an old project from mongoose 3 to 6 and can't seem to find anything in the change docs about `modelSchemas` and how they've been superseded.. In some  unit tests, I have this v3 code;

```
function clearModels(models) {
  models.forEach(model => {
    delete mongoose.models[model];
    delete mongoose.modelSchemas[model];
  });
}
```

This of course fails because `mongoose.modelSchemas` no longer exists -- so the question is, how do I re-write this in a v6 compatible way?